# JAVA PROGRAMMING: Linkedlist question Collection<?> c

Tags: java, linked-list

can you exaplain how

```
public default boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

specifically

```
(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

and `(Collection<?> c)`  works?

Also, can you explain what this mean:

```
public default <T> T[] toArray(T[] array)
```

Comment: Read about [Generics in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: @Investicoder Welcome to SO. Please Google more before asking a question. Show what effort you have invested before asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

`(Collection<T extends E> c)`, T and ? can be the same especially if ? is used like this `(Collection <? extends E) c)`. Usage of wildcard here `(Collection<? Extends E>)` is violated as this is now for a specific object hierarchy not for all object types

Wildcard should not be limited to a specific object type.

but you need to specify the type of T, basically T must be an instance of a certain object hierarchy.

The wildcard can be of any type.

`public default <T> T[] toArray(T[] array)` this is where the usage of ? is the same as T because the type of T is not defined, since you cannot use any special character in naming or specifying types, you can use T to replace ?.
this is an interface method someone must implement the interface that has this method and provide T, and T can be a `LinkedList` or any `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

- `public default boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`

Say you have `class A`, and `class B extends A`.
Then `List<A>.addAll` will do something like:

```
void addAll(Set<B> bs) {
    for (A a : bs) {
        add(a);
    }
}
```

- `public default <T> T[] toArray(T[] array)`

Of course `default` allows to have a method with implementation in the interface.

To convert a `List<T>` to an array `T[]` there is one problem: at runtime java's *type erasure* means there is just a List of Objects. To receive the correct class for the array elements, the design was changed from

```
List<C>
C[] toArray()    // NOT possible, 

<T> T[] toArray(T[] sample)
```

If the parameter (`sample` here) has the correct size, then that array is taken, otherwise a new array is created.

```
List<String> list = ... // At runtime simply a List of Object.

String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); // Created array taken.
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]); // New array created.
```

Now one might think the first version being more optimal, best.
And indeed it is often mentioned to use the more circumstantial form.

However it was shown to me, that the second version is faster. It uses an other byte code array construction.